# I want to get the last record from oracle using rownumber()

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

here am using oracle query for below record, i want to last rownumber 11 record.

```
     select max(t.atdatetime),
     t.lead,
     t.sysid,
     row_number() over(partition by t.sysid order by t.lead desc) as "number" from psd.psd_empreport t where t.sysid in(5350) group by t.lead, t.sysid   order by 2 desc

        SNO   datetime              tlcode  ecode  rownumb

         1  7/2/2013 6:00:25 AM      67    5350     1
         2  10/27/2014 8:30:34 AM   5508    5350    2
         3  10/24/2014 8:30:21 AM   5477    5350    3
         4  9/22/2012 12:28:20 AM   5051    5350    4
         5  10/10/2012 12:28:47 AM  4736    5350    5
         6  5/13/2014 8:24:21 AM    4459    5350    6
         7  9/12/2012 12:28:01 AM   3688    5350    7
         8  2/7/2013 12:32:34 AM    227     5350    8
         9  3/27/2013 12:34:39 AM   140     5350    9
        10  3/1/2013 12:33:27 AM    13      5350    10
        11  9/9/2014 8:28:41 AM     122     5350    11
```

Comment: What error are you getting? I don't see a question here...

Comment: change sort direction and get first row

Comment: i m not getting error. just i need highest row number of record in the above result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want to last rownumber 11 record.

You just need to `ORDER BY DESC` in the **ROW_NUMBER()** window and then select the row having the row_number as 1 from the **subquery**.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM
  3    ( SELECT empno, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY empno DESC) rn FROM emp
  4    )
  5  WHERE rn = 1;

     EMPNO         RN
---------- ----------
      7934          1
```

So, make your existing query a **subquery** and **filter** the row_number as `where rn = 1`.

Comment: @AnandVignesh You're welcome. Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Comment: @AnandVignesh, On the top left of my answer, you will see a faded tick mark, once you click on it it turns green which means you have accepted the answer, in turn you would gain some reputation too. You could also upvote the answer by clicking the up arrow icon beside the green flag. I would suggest you please go through the Stack Overflow tour here http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Yes lalit, i did. Thnx